# Find closest point on HoughLine

Tags: python, typescript, geometry, hough-transform

Given a hough line as `{rho: number, theta: number}` and a coordinate as `{x: number, y: number}`, how would I find the closest point on that hough line to the given coordinate?

So in the following sample graphic, I have the blue line and the red dot, and I'm looking for the white cross.

[image: Graphic]

I'm using Typescript, but I'd appreciate answers in any language or format, since this is technically more of a math problem.

Comment: This is a typical math problem, not OpenCV programming. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White cross is projection of red point `C` onto the line.

At first get components of normal vector to line

```
nx = cos(theta)
ny = sin(theta)
```

and direction vector of line is

```
dx = -ny
dy = nx
```

To find this projection, we need some point `A` at the line. Let's this point is

```
ax = rho * nx
ay = rho * ny
```

and get vector AC

```
acx = cx - ax
acy = cy - ay
```

Now calculate projection using dot product

```
coeff = dx*acx + dy*acy
px = ax + dx * coeff
py = ay + dy * coeff
```

Quick-made Python test (not well tested)

```
import math
def projection_onto_houghline(rho, theta, cx, cy):
   dx = -math.sin(theta)
   dy = math.cos(theta)
   ax = rho * dy
   ay = -rho * dx
   acx = cx - ax
   acy = cy - ay
   coeff = dx*acx + dy*acy
   px = ax + dx * coeff
   py = ay + dy * coeff
   return(px, py)

print(projection_onto_houghline(math.sqrt(2), math.pi/4, 0, 0))
print(projection_onto_houghline(math.sqrt(2), math.pi/4, 2.5, 2))

(1.0000000000000002, 1.0000000000000002)
(1.2500000000000002, 0.7500000000000002)
```

[image]

Comment: The point `A` is not necessary, because line normal directional component of the result point should be `rho`.  (Posted as my answer)

Comment: @fana But you are using the same components - normal `rho*N` and tangential `T*C.dot(T)` , expressions are quite similar, explicit writing `A` means nothing

Comment: Your `A` is described as "some point A at the line".
This point is not restricted to `rho*N` only.
I think, my post is specific to {rho,theta} and yours is more general ({one point and normal/trangential}).

Comment: (Yes, quite similar. And also I understand that purpose of the `A` is N-directional component and so `rho*N` is most natural choice)

Comment: @fana Yes, I wanted some point, and used the easiest one. Still don't see a difference in expressions and result.

Comment: About equation, if modifying yours a bit, it becomes to one I described.
(Of cause, result is same.)
Difference is only "what thinking" / "Presence or absence of concept about `A` and `AC`". And I think this point is "differ". But if many others do not think so, my post is "duplicated".

Answer (score 0):

For the red point `C`, what you should do is

1. Calculate line tangential directional component of the `C`
2. Add `rho * N` to 1. (where, N is unit normal vector of the line)

**memo** (: meaning of above)
For example, if problem is "line is x=x0", what to do?
This case, just modify the x component value of the point `C` to `x0`.
Above steps is just doing this but on another coordinate system. Basis of the coordinate system is normal and tangential of the line.

```cpp
//This code sample is C++, and using OpenCV to visualize
//
#include <random>

class Rnd
{
public:
    Rnd() : m_MT( std::random_device().operator()() ){}
    double GetReal( double Min, double Max ){   return std::uniform_real_distribution<double>( Min,Max )( m_MT );   }
private:
    std::mt19937 m_MT;
};

//main
int main()
{
    constexpr int ImgSize = 320;
    cv::Mat ShowImg = cv::Mat::zeros( ImgSize,ImgSize, CV_8UC3 );

    constexpr int nTest = 3;
    const cv::Scalar DrawColor[nTest] = { {255,96,96}, {0,255,0}, {0,0,255} };

    Rnd rnd;
    for( int i=0; i<nTest; ++i )
    {
        //Line Parameter
        double rho = rnd.GetReal( 10, ImgSize-10 );
        double theta = rnd.GetReal( 0, CV_PI*0.5 );

        cv::Vec2d N{ cos(theta), sin(theta) };  //Line Unit Normal
        cv::Vec2d T{ -N[1], N[0] };  //Line Unit Tangential

        //The Point C
        cv::Vec2d C{ rnd.GetReal( 0, ImgSize ), rnd.GetReal( 0, ImgSize ) };
        //The Answer Point X
        //What you should calculate is this.
        cv::Vec2d X = T*C.dot(T)  +  rho*N;

        {//Draw Result
            {//Draw Line
                cv::Vec2d A = rho * N;
                cv::Vec2d P1 = A - ImgSize * T;
                cv::Vec2d P2 = A + ImgSize * T;
                cv::line( ShowImg, cv::Point(P1), cv::Point(P2), DrawColor[i], 2 );
            }
            {//Draw Point C and X
                cv::circle( ShowImg, cv::Point(C), 5, DrawColor[i], -1 );
                cv::circle( ShowImg, cv::Point(X), 5, DrawColor[i], -1 );
                cv::line( ShowImg, cv::Point(C), cv::Point(X), DrawColor[i]*0.6 );
            }
        }
    }

    cv::imshow( "Result", ShowImg );
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

This is a result of above code.

- 3 examples are drawn in different colors.
- Lines are drawn slightly thicker

[image]